# Try to publish with Azure App Service, and getting a 500 error. Logs attached

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, single-page-application

I have made a boilerplate .net 5.0 react SPA (I didnt do anything to it,  literally just the boilerplate from dotnet),  and then tried to publish it to Azure devops.  I have created the app service, and the sql database and everything seemed to work, however I get a 500 status error when I try to load the page, saying the page cannot handle the request.  I have the logs attached here,  perhaps someone can make some better sense of this and let me know what I am missing? It seems like something to do with signing credentials,  and I don't even know what that is at this point.  I think I am really in over my head but really want to learn.

[image: Page 1]

[image]

Edit:  Added the startup file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using SpaTest.Data;
using SpaTest.Models;

namespace SpaTest {
    public class Startup {
        public Startup( IConfiguration configuration ) {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration {
            get;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services ) {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>( options =>
                 options.UseSqlServer(
                     Configuration.GetConnectionString( "DefaultConnection" ) ) );

            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>( options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true )
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles( configuration => {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            } );
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env ) {
            if ( env.IsDevelopment() ) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            } else {
                app.UseExceptionHandler( "/Error" );
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints( endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}" );
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            } );

            app.UseSpa( spa => {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if ( env.IsDevelopment() ) {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer( npmScript: "start" );
                }
            } );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the startup.cs file ?

Comment: Absolutely,  added it in the main post.  It is the boilerplate only,  I have not changed anything.

Comment: i couldn't find anything wrong. Seems to me some service is not registered in your Startup.cs which gave you the null reference from the error log, but as you said, this is just boilerplate. I would comment services.AddDbContext block,   services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter, services.AddDefaultIdentity, and publish a new version. Then, uncomment one by one to figure out which one is raising the error

Comment: Upon further investigation,  the release version running locally also gives the same 500 error response that I got when deploying to Azure.  So not sure if that gives some better implication of what may be causing the issue.

Comment: really hard to help as I cannot reproduce this error ...

Comment: try to upload what you have to a public github repo

Comment: https://dev.azure.com/pauluhrich/_git/SPATest

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ [ctrldot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426962/ctrldot) for your insights.

Try to add `application insights` or Add `error handling techniques` to your App. Which is used to find the cause of the issue.

Check the `Config file` and `Startup code` if it is causing any issue.

You can use KUDU console by targeting [https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net](https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/) . You will be able to navigate in the debugging console to see the RAW logs from IIS. See [KUDU](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki) for more info.

Refer [here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36968885/15997690)

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out.  That boilerplate uses Identity Server 4,  which requires having a self signed certificate either in the solution itself,  or stored in Azure,  as well as having a B1 level app service subscription.  Once this was sorted out,  no issues whatsoever.