# How to debug server-side execution of web api request?

Tags: c#, azure, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have made an ASP.NET Web API in C# that uses a third party .dll. It is based on the the standard ASP.NET Web API / C# template.

I have deployed it on Azure.

Some test header that just returns hello world is responding fine.

However, when I call the other header that runs my extensive code, I get an error 500.

Let's say I'm new to this and need guidance. I would like to know how to get a precise idea of where the code fails on the server side? It runs just fine on the local server.

Here is the log I'm getting from Azure:

1. IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
2. IIS was not able to access the `web.config` file for the Web site or application. This can occur if
3. the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
4. IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
5. The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
6. The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Any help is welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: si it is deployed on a VM ?

Comment: You can view detailed error messages by navigating to the log stream and selecting Application Logs: click on portal.azure.com/#home, and click on your site, on the left menu under monitoring click on App service log to enable the logs. Similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967675/how-to-resolve-error-500-on-azure-web-app

Answer (score 0):

When encountering an HTTP 500 error when calling a specific endpoint of your ASP.NET Web API on Azure, troubleshooting can be a daunting task. However, there is a methodical approach that can assist you in identifying and resolving the issue. Here are the steps to help you diagnose and pinpoint the problem:

Firstly, check the Azure Application Logs. These logs can help you identify the problem. You can find these logs by going to your App Service on the Azure portal. Once there, under the "Monitoring" section, select "App Service logs." Enable the necessary diagnostic logs, such as "Application Logging," "Failed Request Tracing," and "Detailed error messages." Reproduce the issue, and then check the logs for detailed error messages and stack traces.

Next, review your application code, especially the code executed when calling the problematic endpoint. Look for potential issues such as unhandled exceptions, dependencies on third-party DLL, and logging. Adding extensive logging to your code can help track the flow and identify the point where it fails.

Ensure that your web.config file is correctly configured and deployed to Azure. The error message mentions issues related to web.config, so validate that it's accessible and properly configured. Additionally, verify that the application pool identity in Azure has the necessary permissions to access the required resources, including the DLL and any files or databases your application relies on.

Make sure any external dependencies or required components are installed and configured correctly on Azure. If the issue remains unresolved, consider setting up remote debugging on Azure. This will allow you to attach a debugger to your running Azure application and inspect variables and code execution in real time. This can be a powerful way to identify the root cause of the error.

Sometimes, a simple restart of your Azure App Service can resolve internal server errors caused by temporary issues. If you're unable to resolve the issue after performing the above steps, consider reaching out to Azure support for assistance. They can help you investigate further and diagnose complex issues.

When debugging in a production environment, be sure to take appropriate precautions as it can potentially expose sensitive information. It's often a good practice to create a staging environment that mimics your production environment closely for testing and debugging purposes. By following these steps and carefully reviewing the logs and code, you should be able to pinpoint the exact cause of the HTTP 500 error on your Azure-hosted ASP.NET Web API.